# Please, how do I change this animation from kotlin to swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I investigated but I could not find anything like this for Swift. Can you please help me make this animation in Swift?

```
Val animador = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f ,1.0f)
animador.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
animador.interpolator= LinearInterpolator()
animador.duration = 10000L

animador.addUpdateListener { animation ->
val progreso = animador.animatedValue as Float
Val anchura = fondo!!.width
fondo!!.traslationx = transicionX
fondo2!!.traslationx = transicion X -anchura

}
animador.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly right, but try this:

```
let anchura = fondo.frame.width
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
    fondo.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(transicionX)
    fondo2.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(transicionX) - anchura
})
```

Swift animations start automatically (no need to `start()` or anything).

#### Edit:

Inside the `animations` block, you just put the **final value** that you want. This means that you don't need to calculate the progress or anything, and you probably don't even need a `transicionX` variable. Instead, try this:

```
let anchura = fondo.frame.width /// let's say this is 50
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
    fondo.frame.origin.x += anchura /// move fondo to the right by 50
    fondo2.frame.origin.x -= anchura /// move fondo2 to the left by 50
})
```

*Another edit: made it `+=` and `-=` to animate on top of existing values*

Comment: @Sebastian like `var transicionX = 50`. But that's a really basic question. You might want to revisit some of this.

Comment: Excuse me, I forgot to put in the question that transitionX = width * progress and I don't know how to convert these variables to swift(progreso ), since you helped me to declare "width", thanks for your help, I appreciate it -

Comment: Ah! With `UIView.animate`, you don't calculate the progress. It's **automatic**. Inside the `animations` block, you put the value that you want *in the end*. Everything else is automatic.